# Cant load index.php page with apache using vagrant and virtualbox

Tags: php, virtualbox, vagrant

This is my vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/inicio.sh"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/raring/current/raring-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8085, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "funcook"
    end

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network :public_network

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  #   # Don't boot with headless mode
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
  #   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you're using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file base.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # An example Puppet manifest to provision the message of the day:
  #
  # # group { "puppet":
  # #   ensure => "present",
  # # }
  # #
  # # File { owner => 0, group => 0, mode => 0644 }
  # #
  # # file { '/etc/motd':
  # #   content => "Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine!
  # #               Managed by Puppet.\n"
  # # }
  #
  # config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  #   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  #   puppet.manifest_file  = "init.pp"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
  # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding
  # some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  # config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  #   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
  #   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
  #   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
  #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  #   chef.add_role "web"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
  # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
  #
  # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
  # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
  # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
  # validation key to validation.pem.
  #
  # config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
  #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
  #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
  # end
  #
  # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
  # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
  # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
  #
  #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
end
```

And this is the content of inicio.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ ! -f ~/initial_provosioning_done ];
then
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    apt-get update  
    apt-get install -y -q lamp-server^ php5-gd
    sed -i 's,www-data,vagrant,g' /etc/apache2/envvars
    sed -i 's,/var/www,/vagrant/www,g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    sed -i 's,AllowOverride None,AllowOverride All,g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
    mysqladmin -u root password root
    mysql -uroot -proot < /vagrant/bd/script.sql
    rm -r /var/lock/apache2
    a2enmod rewrite
    service apache2 restart
    touch ~/initial_provosioning_done
fi
```

This is how I am starting the VM:

```
    minirafa:beta.funcook.com TONIWEB$ vagrant reload
    [default] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    [default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
    [default] Creating shared folders metadata...
    [default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    [default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    [default] Forwarding ports...
    [default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
    [default] -- 80 => 8085 (adapter 1)
    [default] Booting VM...
    [default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    [default] Machine booted and ready!
    [default] Mounting shared folders...
    [default] -- /vagrant
    minirafa:beta.funcook.com TONIWEB$
```

The thing is that:

Chrome will log:

`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

and:

```
minirafa:~ TONIWEB$ curl 'http://localhost:80'
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Or:

```
minirafa:~ TONIWEB$ curl 'http://localhost:8085'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
minirafa:~ TONIWEB$
```

Usually this settings work for me with other projects,

Any idea what could I try next?

-EDIT-

Also:

```
minirafa:beta.funcook.com TONIWEB$ curl -v http://localhost:8085
* About to connect() to localhost port 8085 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8085 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost:8085
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
minirafa:beta.funcook.com TONIWEB$
```

Comment: What happens when you visit http://localhost:8085 in your browser?

Comment: @sundance chrome says: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (that's why I tried using curl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're trying to reach localhost on port 80 with curl, you're actually trying to reach the host machine (not the guest running in virtualbox/vagrant). So if the host doesn't run a webserver (on port 80), it's normal you get a `couldn't connect to host` message.

You should be trying to reach localhost on port 8085, because that's the port you're forwarding to port 80 on the guest machine. And that apparently tells you `Empty reply from server`...

I cannot say much about this, unless I can get some additional info about the webserver running on the guest:

- Is it running properly? (check the error-logs)
- Does it respond to requests from inside the guest machine?
- Does the request from the host reach the webserver? (check the access-logs)
- If so, does the webserver encounter errors? (check the error-logs)
- If not, is there a firewall is running on the guest, dropping requests to port 80?

PS: Just a tip: You could create a private network on the guest by enabling this line:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

This way you can reach the webserver at `192.168.33.10:80`, and won't need to forward any ports to it.